Add custom field to wagtailadmin ModelAdmin
I'm trying to add a custom field to wagtail ModelAdmin, but not sure how to do that. I tried
from wagtail_modeladmin.options import ModelAdmin, modeladmin_register
from wagtail_modeladmin.views import EditView
from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin.utils import quote
from wagtail.log_actions import registry as log_registry

from dzen_wagtail.football_maps.models import FootballMap


class FootballMapAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    extra_link = forms.URLField(
        label="Extra link",
        widget=forms.URLInput(attrs={"type": "button"}),
    )
    field_order = ["tg", "name", "location", "history", "covering", "extra_link", "status"]

    class Meta:
        model = FootballMap
        fields = ["tg", "name", "location", "history", "covering", "extra_link", "status"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FootballMapAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["extra_link"].initial = "https://example.com"


class FootballMapEditView(EditView):
    def get_form(self):
        return FootballMapAdminForm(instance=self.instance)


@modeladmin_register
class FootballMapAdminSite(ModelAdmin):
    model = FootballMap
    menu_label = "Карта коробок"
    menu_icon = "circle-check"
    edit_view_class = FootballMapEditView

    def get_list_display(self, request):
        list_display = ["location", "status"]
        return list_display

But looks like I go in wrong direction, and such can be achieved in ModelAdmin itself

It looks like you put everything in the same file.
The FootballMapAdminForm should go into views.py
And everything related to FootballMapAdminSite(ModelAdmin) into wagtail_hooks.py (needs to be created) within your Apps Folder.
